# Multiple Bindings to a Single Delegate Causing Duplicate Event Fires

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

I have a `Get` function in my `UGameInstanceBase` C++ class that makes an HTTP request and binds the response to an `OnAPIRequestCompleted` delegate. However, when I bind this delegate to different events in Blueprints, all of them get called even if the delegate is triggered only once.

Here's the C++ code for my Get method and the delegate broadcast:

```
void UGameInstanceBase::Get(const FString& apiEndPoint) {
    // ... HTTP request setup ...
    HttpRequest->OnProcessRequestComplete().BindUObject(this, &UGameInstanceBase::OnResponseReceived);
    HttpRequest->ProcessRequest();
}

void UGameInstanceBase::OnResponseReceived(FHttpRequestPtr Request, FHttpResponsePtr Response, bool bWasSuccessful) {
    if (bWasSuccessful) {
        FString ResponseString = Response->GetContentAsString();
        OnAPIRequestCompleted.Broadcast(ResponseString);
    } else {
        OnAPIRequestCompleted.Broadcast("");  // or some error message
    }
}

// Delegate definition
DECLARE_DYNAMIC_MULTICAST_DELEGATE_OneParam(FOnAPIRequestCompleted, FString, ResponseData);
```

And in my Blueprint, I have two separate bindings to this delegate, expecting them to be called independently:

Binding at location 1 in the Blueprint (intended for one type of response).
Binding at location 2 in the Blueprint (intended for another type of response).
However, when I trigger the delegate from a response, both bindings are called.

I need to ensure that each call to `Get` results in only the corresponding event being called in the Blueprint.

Could someone explain why this might be happening and how I can ensure that each Get request only calls its corresponding response event in the Blueprint?

[image]

Comment: You are binding to the same MULTICAST-delegate, why do you expect them to be called independently? That's what MULTICAST is for, if you want to call something regardless of the number of callees. What you can do is adding a parameter to the delegate that helps you identify the sender and discard it, if it isn't relevant to the callee, e.g. an enum value or just a simple integer.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a single delegate (it's a member variable in one of your classes), and binding all events to it. The delegate type is "dynamic *mulitcast*", which means you can bind many events to it, and they will all fire. It seems to be wrong type of delegate to use for the goal you're describing.

If you want to make a delegate that only binds to one event, and is indepedently bound on each function call, you need a non-multicast delegate. If you want to use it in Blueprint, it should be a dynamic delegate.

So first, declare the delegate in your `.h` file like so `DECLARE_DYNAMIC_DELEGATE_OneParam(FOnAPIRequestCompleted, FString, ResponseData)`.

You don't need to save it to a member variable, as you want one to be created every time you call this function. So you can make it an input variable of the function itself: `void UGameInstanceBase::Get(const FString& ApiEndPoint, FOnAPIRequestCompleted OnResult)`. Then, in this function, you need to bind it to receiving your response. The easiest way is to use a lambda function:

```cpp
const auto Callback = FHttpRequestCompleteDelegate::CreateLambda(
    [OnResult](FHttpRequestPtr Req, FHttpResponsePtr Resp, bool Success) {
        // whatever you need to do
        OnResult.ExecuteIfBound(/* your result string */);
    }
);

HttpRequest->OnProcessRequestComplete() = *Callback;
// whatever setup you need
HttpRequest->ProcessRequest();
```

This way an event-type pin will appear on your function call, and each time you can bind a different response as needed. You can then create an event in BP that is connected to that pin.

The resulting flow is then like this: request is processed, the `IHttpRequest`'s `OnProcessRequestComplete()` is called, which calls the lambda, which in turn calls the dynamic delegate, which calls the Blueprint event/function.